# How do I find Account Owner from Contact

Tags: account, contact, owner

I have Contact Id and I want to find email of Account Owner not Owner of contact.Can you please provide me ref that what is the relation of contact with Account and how do we get Account Owner from contact.

Comment: Is it Apex, formula field, VF lightning?

Comment: Trying from SOQL queries Using Resetforce

Comment: The SOQL is on Contact?

Comment: Restforce force and queries 
`account_owner_id = @client.query(“select AccountId  from #{TABLE_NAME} where id = ‘#{id}‘“).first.try(:AccountId)
   @client.query(“select Email,FirstName from user where id = ‘#{account_owner_id}’“).first if account_owner_id.present?`

Comment: There are many good resources on Salesforce Trailhead and in the documentation on SOQL basics and querying with relationships.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can direcly use the below query.

```
Select id,Account.OwnerId From Contact
```

Account.OwnerID will return account ownerId.